# poetry tries to install project folder as a dependency: EnvCommandError

Tags: python, python-poetry

I am trying to run `poetry install` command, but I get the following error:

```
[EnvCommandError]
Command ['pip', 'install', '-e', '<PROJECT_FOLDER_PATH>'] errored with 
the following return code 1, and output: 
Obtaining file:///<PROJECT_FOLDER_PATH>
ERROR: Package '<subfolder>' requires a different Python: 3.6.8 not in '>=3.7,<4.0'
```

Where my project directory containing `.toml` file is marked as `<PROJECT_FOLDER>` (`PROJECT_FOLDER_PATH` is, correspondingly, it's full path), and it contains `<subfolder>`.

Part of my `toml` file:

```
[tool.poetry]
name = "<PROJECT_FOLDER>"
version = "0.1.0"
description = ""
authors = ["Your Name <you@example.com>"]

[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.7"
```

It seems that poetry tries to install the project itself as a dependency, but for some reason that I don't understand it seems the conflicting Python version. I temporarily solved it by setting `python = "^3.6"`, but now the issue is back, as I need  some package which only accepts `python = "^3.7"`.

Comment: You didn't ask a question.

Comment: @jordanm I get a mentioned error code and I don't want to get the mentioned error code. I (wrongly, it seems) assumed, that it was a bit obvious.

Comment: Are you running poetry within a virtuell environment or disable creation of virtualenvs in the config? The python version poetry uses to install your package is 3.6.8. But the `pyproject.toml` says it need at least python 3.7.